# Is there a deeper reason for the classification of moduli in which a primitive root exists?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, primitive-roots

The **primitive root theorem** classifies the set of moduli for which a primitive root exists as $$1,2,4,p^k,2p^k$$ where $p$ is an odd prime and $k$ is a positive integer.

I have worked through a proof of this assertion which can be broken down as follows:

1. It is clear that $1,2,4$ each have a primitive root.
2. Higher powers of $2$ do not have a primitive root by induction.
3. If the modulus has an odd prime factor and the modulus has a primitive root, then the modulus is either a power of that prime or twice a power of that prime.
4. Every odd prime has a primitive root (using polynomials in modular arithmetic).
5. Primitive roots modulo a prime can be "lifted" to moduli that are higher powers of the prime.
6. Primitive roots in a modulus can be lifted to twice that modulus.

This is all well and good, but this proof just works towards the expected result using standard elementary techniques without providing much insight. I was wondering: **Is there a deep reason for why the classification of suitable moduli is so strange?** It's a natural question to wonder when a reduced residue system has a multiplicative generator, yet the set we end up with carves out an unexpected subset of the positive integers.

I don't entirely know what would qualify as a satisfactory answer, but some possibilities are:

- The set of integers $1,2,4,p^k,2p^k$ appears in other parts of mathematics.
- There is a more general theorem of which this is merely a shadow.
- There is a different proof that is less reminiscent of mechanical verification.

EDIT: I came across a couple of quotes that sum up my feelings.

What the standard proof is like, if I may exaggerate:

> Well, I have slightly mixed feelings about [the classification of finite simple groups]. First of all, it takes so many pages to prove; it seems to me the degree of understanding must be pretty limited if that is the only way it can be done. - *Michael Atiyah, The Mathematical Intelligencer*

What I'm looking for:

> Not only is the above combinatorial proof much shorter than our previous proof, but it also makes the reason for the simple answer completely transparent. It is often the case, as occurred here, that the first proof to come to mind turns out to be laborious and inelegant, but that the final answer suggests a simpler combinatorial proof. - *Richard Stanley, Enumerative Combinatorics I*

Comment: Note:  $x^2\equiv1\bmod 2^n$ has more than two solutions for $n\ge3$, because $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1),$ and $x+1$ and $x-1$ have the same parity

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I read your comment a few times, but I'm not quite grasping why you wrote it.

Comment: $x^2\equiv1\bmod m$ has more than two solutions means $m$ does not have a primitive root, right?

Comment: I believe @J.W.Tanner's suggestion will also extend to rule out any number with two distinct odd prime factors (use the CRT and I believe it will be clear that there are at least 4 zeros of $x^2-1$ in this case) as well as when it is divisible by $4$ and an odd prime (one simply needs two summands in which $1\neq -1$ to get more than 4 solutions to $x^2-1$).

Comment: Yes, step 3 in my outline does that in essentially the same way. I suppose what would be interesting is if there were a proof that did not eliminate the bad possibilities and then construct a primitive root in the good possibilities, but instead there were a direct unified proof. An analogy would be the search for a bijective proof of a combinatorial identity instead of a proof by casework.

Comment: The deeper reason is the CRT. If $n = \prod p_k^{e_k}$, then we have a ring isomorphism $$\mathbb{Z}/(n) \cong \prod \mathbb{Z}/(p_k^{e_k})\,,$$ and correspondingly an isomorphism of the unit groups $$U(n) \cong \prod U(p_k^{e_k})\,.$$ All nontrivial factors there have even order, so $U(n)$ cannot be cyclic unless there is at most one nontrivial factor. Thus one needs to examine the structure of $U(p^e)$ (and notes that $U(2)$ is trivial).

Comment: @DanielFischer that elminates cases, but the proof of cyclicity of the other cases remain. For that, I am only aware of a fairly involved argument in the prime case followed by a lifting argument for the prime power case.

Comment: Well, it shows that only numbers of the form $p^{e}$ or $2p^{e}$ *can* have primitive roots, and why. That all of these except for $2^{e}$ with $e \geqslant 3$ indeed have primitive roots is a different matter. I agree that the lifting of the exponent isn't the most illuminating proof ever, but at least it's a simple and clear argument that shows it works. As for the prime case, I don't think the proof that every finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic is *that* involved, but yes, an argument that makes it more imediately clear why that is so would be nice.